# Bigquery how to schedule a weekly insert job

Tags: insert, scheduled-tasks, google-bigquery, etl

I'm using bigquery to analyse logs on my website.
There is some simple data which i'm extracting on a weekly basis using a simple SQL query i.e.
SELECT a,b,c from table dates are in week 1

I would like to set up a process where I can get this data automatically into a data set at the end of each week so I dont have to run the query every week and I can store the results so I dont run a query against a lot of history if I need to see it again

What would you advise for this process?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd say look into programming a cron job ([python](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/config/cron), [java](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/config/cron)), to do it for you.

Considering your use-case is pretty easy, it shouldn't be too complicated to set it up

Comment: do you have any example scripts I can look at?

Comment: @shecode I'd suggest looking at the doc I linked (python or java, your language of choice) and exploring. I don't have anything on hand, no, but BQ is pretty straightforward, and uploading a cron is very easy